# count number of black pixels in an image in Python with OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv

I have the following test code in Python to read, threshold and display an image:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np 
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

# read image
img = cv2.imread('slice-309.png',0)
ret,thresh = cv2.threshold(img,0,230, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
height, width = img.shape
print "height and width : ",height, width
size = img.size
print "size of the image in number of pixels", size 

# plot the binary image
imgplot = plt.imshow(img, 'gray')
plt.show()
```

I would like to count the number of pixels within the image with a certain label, for instance black.
How can I do that ? I looked at tutorials of OpenCV but did not find any help :-(

Thanks!

Answer (score 23, accepted):

For black images you get the total number of pixels (rows*cols) and then subtract it from the result you get from [`cv2.countNonZero(mat)`](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#countnonzero).

For other values, you can create a mask using [`cv2.inRange()`](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html?highlight=inrange#inrange) to return a binary mask showing all the locations of the color/label/value you want and then use `cv2.countNonZero` to count how many of them there are.

UPDATE (Per Miki's comment):

When trying to find the count of elements with a particular value, Python allows you to skip the `cv2.inRange()` call and just do:

```
cv2.countNonZero(img == scalar_value)
```

Comment: Thanks  a lot! I tried and in fact when using cv2 I have to use countNonZero instead of CountNonZero with cv. Another question: when I do cv2.countNonZero(thresh)
I get the total number of pixels instead of the number of pixels that are not black.... do you know why?

Comment: I updated my answer, the function name should not have been capitalized.  It seems all of your pixels are not black...trying looking at `thresh`, it might not be what you think it is.  If that doesn't work, mark your preferred answer on this question to show it is resolved and ask another question showing your code.  Put a link to that question here and I'll help you out more.

Comment: sorry it works! Thanks again for the help!!! you are right my threshold was not well defined in my function threshold....

Comment: Good answer. In python there's an equivalent of this C++ code `countNonZero(img == scalar_value);`?

Answer (score 3):

```
import cv2
image = cv2.imread("pathtoimg", 0)
count = cv2.countNonZero(image)
print(count)
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, thanks for answering! Please update your answer with some non-code text describing how this solves the problem at hand.