# Counting white pixels in image

Tags: python-3.x

very new to python. I have used code found in guides etc to try and grab the white pixles in an image but getting stuck. Probably super easy but my if statement to select white is not playing ball. Can anyone help?

```
#***convert image to no pixels per shade output
import cv2
import numpy as np
from collections import defaultdict 
img = cv2.imread('..\\Snapshots\\Me.png')
pixels = img.reshape(-1,3)
counts = defaultdict(int)
for pixel in pixels:
if pixel[0] == pixel[1] == pixel[2]:
    counts[pixel[0]] += 1
for pv in sorted(counts.keys()):
print("(%d,%d,%d): %d pixels" % (pv, pv, pv, counts[pv]))



#***count white pixels
from PIL import Image  
im = Image.open('..\\snapshots\\Me.png')
white = 0
other = 0
for pixel in im.getdata():
if pixel == (255, 255, 255, 255): # if your image is RGB (if RGBA, (0, 0,     0, 255) or so
    white += 1
else:
    other += 1
print('white=' + str(white)+', Other='+str(other))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

white rgb is `(255, 255, 255)` not `(255, 255, 255, 255)`

Also try:

```
countNonZero(pixel == 255)
```

(from here: [count number of black pixels in an image in Python with OpenCV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32590932/count-number-of-black-pixels-in-an-image-in-python-with-opencv))

Comment: Fantastic thanks, really helped! Played with it some more and understand where I was going wrong. I had converted to greyscale so just needed the 1 255.

Comment: @JDoe No problem. glad I could help

Answer (score 0):

The above code has some formatting issues. Hence, I am posting here the corrected version of that code. It may be helpful for others.

```
#***convert image to no pixels per shade output
import cv2
import numpy as np
from collections import defaultdict 
img = cv2.imread('/Users/monjoysaha/Downloads/generated_images/gen_1.png')
pixels = img.reshape(-1,3)
counts = defaultdict(int)
for pixel in pixels:
    if pixel[0] == pixel[1] == pixel[2]:
       counts[pixel[0]] += 1
for pv in sorted(counts.keys()):
    print("(%d,%d,%d): %d pixels" % (pv, pv, pv, counts[pv]))



#***count white pixels
from PIL import Image  
im = Image.open('/Users/monjoysaha/Downloads/generated_images/gen_1.png')
white = 0
other = 0
for pixel in im.getdata():
    if pixel == (255, 255, 255, 255): # if your image is RGB (if RGBA, (0, 0,     0, 255) or so
       white += 1
    else:
        other += 1
print('white=' + str(white)+', Other='+str(other))
```