# Find which image has most black color

Tags: python, opencv, colors

First of all am dividing an video frame into three different frames. And then I converted that image to an Gray scale image. After converting I need to find which frame has most black colour than other two frame. I don't know how to find how much black is present in an image.

I have been go through with some methods in internet but I don't know how to implement them?

```
import cv2
import sys
sys.path.append('/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages')

import cv2
import numpy as np
import time
import copy

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while True:
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    output = frame.copy()
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    cv2.imshow('gray',gray)
    cv2.imshow('frame',frame)
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(output, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    gray =255-gray
    ret, thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 225, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)
    output, contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_TREE,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
    output = cv2.drawContours(output, contours, -1,(0,0,255),3)
    cv2.imshow('frame',output)
    height, width = output.shape[:2]
    print (output.shape)

    start_row, start_col = int(0), int(0)
    # Let's get the ending pixel coordinates (bottom right of cropped top)
    end_row, end_col = int(height), int(width*.3)
    cropped_top = output[start_row:end_row , start_col:end_col]
    print (start_row, end_row) 
    print (start_col, end_col)

    cv2.imshow("Cropped Topp", cropped_top) 



    # Let's get the starting pixel coordiantes (top left of cropped bottom)
    start_row, start_col = int(0), int(width*.3)
    # Let's get the ending pixel coordinates (bottom right of cropped bottom)
    end_row, end_col = int(height), int(width)
    cropped_bot = output[start_row:end_row , start_col:end_col]
    print (start_row, end_row )
    print (start_col, end_col)

    ##cv2.imshow("Cropped Bot", cropped_bot) 
    ##cv2.waitKey(0) 
    ##cv2.destroyAllWindows()

    start_row, start_col = int(0), int(0)
    # Let's get the ending pixel coordinates (bottom right of cropped top)
    end_row, end_col = int(height), int(width*.3)
    cropped_top = cropped_bot[start_row:end_row , start_col:end_col]
    print (start_row, end_row) 
    print (start_col, end_col)

    cv2.imshow("Cropped Top", cropped_top) 



    # Let's get the starting pixel coordiantes (top left of cropped bottom)
    start_row, start_col = int(0), int(width*.3)
    # Let's get the ending pixel coordinates (bottom right of cropped bottom)
    end_row, end_col = int(height), int(width)
    cropped_mid = cropped_bot[start_row:end_row , start_col:end_col]
    print (start_row, end_row )
    print (start_col, end_col)

    cv2.imshow("Cropped Bot", cropped_mid) 
##    #cv2.imwrite('plsal1.png',h)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xff == ord('q'):
            break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

i need to know how to detect black colour in an image and relate them with other two image and find which one has most black colour

Comment: You can use `countNonZero(image == scalar_value)`, where scalar_value would be 0 for black pixels and compare the count between the three images. Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32590932/count-number-of-black-pixels-in-an-image-in-python-with-opencv

Comment: If the image you want to check is thresholded (I think it is but am not sure), the mean/average of the image is directly proportional to the amount of white, so if the mean is zero, the image is black, if the mean is 255, the image is white. So an image with more black will have a lower mean.

Comment: How about counting from numpy array (images are numpy arrays in opencv), how many pixels are having RGB 0,0,0? (or from HSV saturation 0) ?

Comment: am not using hsv image am using grayscale in fact i dont know how to impement

Comment: @RickM.i go through that one but i dont know how to implement that in my code.

Comment: Usually for colors analyzing used a histograms. Create it for gray image and calculate sum of first bins on each image. Tutorial: https://docs.opencv.org/4.0.1/d1/db7/tutorial_py_histogram_begins.html

Comment: `countNonZero(gray>small_th)` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi in an b/w image black is considered if the corresponding values for pixel is zero.
So lets say you use open cv and numpy array for the processing we can do something like this.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread('pathOfImg',0) #read img as b/w as an numpy array
unique, counts = np.unique(img, return_counts=True)
mapColorCounts = dict(zip(unique, counts))
```

now `mapColorCounts[0]` will be the num black pixel in an image the more this number the more black the image has.