# How to count number of black pixels in png?

Tags: python, graphics, python-imaging-library, pixel

I have a black and white drawing that was drawn online, so the pixels are *only* solid black or solid white. The drawing is a png, which I am analyzing in python.

```
im = Image.open(os.path.join(dir))
im = img_as_float(im)
plt.imshow(im)
```

Does anyone have advice on how to count the number of black pixels in a png?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [count number of black pixels in an image in Python with OpenCV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32590932/count-number-of-black-pixels-in-an-image-in-python-with-opencv)

Comment: You can access the individual pixels of a PIL `Image` object using its [`getdata()`](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image.getdata) or much slower [`getpixel()`](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image.getpixel) methods. Here's [sample code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40729543/355230) of using the latter on a black & white image (a color image would be very similar).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple script to count black pixels:

```py
def countBlack (image):
    blacks = 0
    for color in image.flatten():
        if color < 0.0001:
            blacks += 1
    return blacks
```

Comment: Thank you! I'm getting the error `''numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'getdata'` when I try this. Do you have advice?

Comment: Awesome, thanks!! I'm new at coding, so do you mind explaining your code? For example, I am now trying to count white pixels (to calculate the proportion of white to black). I changed color to `color > 0.0001` thinking that that's how I'd count white pixels, but the output is less than the original count for black. The png contains more white than black pixels, so I'm confused.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming all pixels are either black or white, this should work:

`len([px for px in list(im.getdata()) if px[1] < 0.01])`

Comment: I also receive this error `'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'getdata'`. But thanks as well!

Comment: My code assumes `im` is an `Image` and not `ndarray`. So you should use it before the `im = img_as_float(im)`. You can add the code for `img_as_float` and we can adapt the answer

Comment: Is this what you mean? I think this returns the total pixels. `for i,im in enumerate(sketch_paths):
    im = Image.open(os.path.join(sketch_dir,f))
    count = len([px for px in list(im.getdata()) if px[1] < 0.01])
    im = img_as_float(im)
    plt.imshow(im)
print(count)` I calculated the total pixels with `im.shape[0] * im.shape[1]` (Ack, so sorry, I'm new and don't know how to properly format my code in this comment!)

Answer (score 0):

Since it's now a numpy array, use a mask and sum:

```
nblack = im[np.where(im==0)].sum()
print(nblack)
```

This assumes - as per your question - solid black. Any other threshold is arbitrary.

Answer (score 0):

If you are opening an image with PIL and expecting a pure, single-channel greyscale image (rather than a colour one or a palettised one) you should ensure that is what you get with:

```
# Open image and ensure single channel greyscale image
im = Image.open(...).convert('L')
```

Explanation [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/52307690/2836621).

You can then convert to a Numpy array with:

```
na = np.array(im)
```

Now, Numpy will count the white pixels for you:

```
white = np.count_nonzero(im)
```

And the black pixels:

```
black = np.count_nonzero(im==0)
```

Alternatively, you can subtract the number of white pixels from the total number of pixels:

```
black = im.size - white
```

Comment: Ah, I realized part of the problem. When I use `.convert('L') `, it turns the entire image black. Do you know what might be going on?

Comment: @psychcoder If you share your image, I can tell pretty quickly.